# Merge a branch of a branch into master without merging the middle branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

## Short version of the question

Given the following branch structure:

```
   *----*-----*
master         \
                *--*---*------*-*---*
                A                    \
                                      *----*
                                    hotfix
```

Is it possible to merge *only* the changes made in `hotfix` into `master` *without* introducing **any** changes made in `Feature A`?

During development of `Feature A`, file_1 was changed. During `hotfix`, file_1 and file_2 was changed.

I want the line by line changes introduced in `hotfix` to be merged into `master`. What I don't want is the exact file as it is in `hotfix` to overwrite the file in `master` because then it will contain `Feature A` changes.

## Backstory

I'm working on our development server. I have a master branch which is (almost) an exact copy of the live server. When I want to implement new features I create a branch off master, make changes and upload to the development server. Once I am happy with the changes I merge them into master and push the changes to the live server.

I have been working on a `Feature A` that is taking a very long time to implement and affects many files. Before completing `Feature A` I want to work on a `hotfix`. I could checkout `master` and branch from there for my hotfix, however all the files on the development server currently contain code for the `Feature A`. I don't want `Feature A` to stop working on dev while I work on `hotfix`. So I have branched off `Feature A`.

I have now completed my `hotfix` and I want to merge it into master. However I don't want **any** `Feature A` code to make it into `master`.

Providing there are no merge conflicts, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since branches are really just named commits, your history actually looks like this: (Latest commit on top)

```
* 9999 [hotfix]
|
* 8888
|
* 7777
|
* 6666 [A]
|
* 5555
|
* 4444
|
* 3333 [master]
|
* 2222
|
V
```

---

```
$ git checkout hotfix
```

First, lets save a pointer to the original `hotfix`, and call it `A-hotfix`:

```
$ git branch A-hotfix
```

Now, take all of the commits from `A` to `hotfix`, and replay them onto the commit where `master` points:

```
$ git rebase --onto master A hotfix
```

Comment: Do I have to be on a specific branch when I run `git rebase --onto master A hotfix` ?

Comment: No. Check out `git help rebase`. You'll see the last argument is which branch to rebase.

Comment: Where does this put `A-hotfix` in relation to master?

Comment: @Speeddymon `A-hotfix` is just another name for the original `hotfix` (`9999`).

Comment: Yes so what I'm asking is that now `A-hotfix` has 3 commits that are in `master` (the more recent 3 commits out of the 6) but there are 3 commits that were put in that branch which are based on the original `master` before the rebase. So how do those 3 commits cleanly merge? It seems `A-hotfix` might be both ahead of and behind master by some number of commits.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `git rebase --onto master A hotfix`.
This will rebase the commits in hotfix but not in branch A onto the tip of your master branch. After that you can merge them into your master branch as always.

Comment: Do I have to be on a specific branch when I run `git rebase --onto master A hotfix` ?